# Azure-DevOps: There was a resource authorization issue: "The pipeline is not valid

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am also getting the error "There was a resource authorization issue: "The pipeline is not valid"
I am running the pipeline from a yml file.
I click on the authorize option that is part of the error and I get the message back that authorization was successful. I verified that my service connection has permissions to all pipelines.
I deleted and recreated the service connection.
Any suggestions please?
What am I over looking.
Thank you

Comment: If the error says the pipeline is not valid I would start there. Is there anyway you can share the yaml file?

Comment: If you edit the pipeline, click the 3 dots and click validate it will let you know if there's any issues with the yml file

Comment: Due to limited information, your issue cannot be identified. Could you share a screenshot showing the current error to help clarify your issue? Also can you share more detailed error messages (part of the debug log) and your YAML file?